# .NET MAUI .NET 7 to 8 Resource Conflict

Tags: .net, maui, .net-8.0

I've made the requisite changes to my csproj file, etc. per the instructions, deleted my bin and obj folders, then cleaned and rebuilt my solution.  It fails with the following:

WINAPPSDKGENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry.

WINAPPSDKGENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI277: 0x80073b0f - Conflicting values for resource 'Files/Microsoft.Maui/Platform/Windows/Styles/WindowRootViewStyle.xbf'

Comment: `I've made the requisite changes to my csproj file`  Can your app compile without changing the file, and what changes did you make to the file?

Answer (score 1):

This message was caused by a 3rd-party library that I had yet to update.

Comment: Please be more specific: what library and how did you update? I'm having the same issue, but it's like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Eventually found it: it was Telerik.UI.for.Maui that needed to be updated.